# Scrapy, trying to crawl multiple pages

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

I’m newbie to scrapy. And in my first project I tried to crawl a web with multi pages. And I grab the data from the first page (index=0) but I’m not able to get the data from the following pages:

https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?sort=default&gt=4-col&offset=4&index=1

https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?sort=default&gt=4-col&offset=4&index=2

https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?sort=default&gt=4-col&offset=4&index=3

....

I tried different `Rules` but it doesn’t work for me.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import myfirstItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.item import Field, Item



class myfirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'myfirst'

start_urls = ["https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad"]
allowed_domains= ["leroymerlin.es"]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= (), restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]/a'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= (), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="boxCard"]')), callback = 'parse_item', follow = False),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    items = myfirstItem()

    product_name = response.css ('.titleTechniqueSheet::text').extract()

    items['product_name'] = product_name

    yield items
```

Despites I have read thousands of posts with the same problem, none of them worked for me.. Any help, please?

*Edit: After the advise of @Fura, I found a better solution for me. This is how it looks:

```
class myfirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myfirst'

    start_urls = ["https://www.leroymerlin.es/decoracion-navidena/arboles-navidad?index=%s" % (page_number) for page_number in range(1,20)]
    allowed_domains= ["leroymerlin.es"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= r'/fp',), callback = 'parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        items = myfirstItem()

        product_name = response.css ('.titleTechniqueSheet::text').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name

        yield items
```

Comment: What is the result when you run your code?

Comment: this page uses `JavaScript` to add links to next pages but scrapy can't run JavaScript. If you turn off JavaScript in browser and load page in browser then you will see that there is no links. You would need [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to work with `splash` which can run `JavaScript`. Eventually [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) to work with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: @Alex: The result of the code looks fine for the first page but it doesn't get anything from the following pages..

Comment: @Furas: I will have a look! Let's see if I'm able to understand how it works! Thanks man!

Comment: `Selenium` can control web browser Chrome/Firefox which can run `JavaScript` and it can gives HTML after running JavaScript.  `Splash` use for this Qt widget `WebKit` which can also display HTML and run JavaScript. And `Splash` was created by authors of `Scrapy`.

Comment: @furas: Thanks again! I had a look into booth solutions but, as far as I see, the performance is lower .. but again: thank you very much!!

Comment: frankly, if you know how looks link to next page then you can genearate links in code without scraping from HTML.